# Update an observable value when other observable value changes in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following  view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Company Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="text: $root.CompnayNameFilter">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="text: $root.PhoneNumberFilter">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>User Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="text: $root.UsernameFilter">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Database Location</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="text: $root.DatabaseLocationFilter">
</div>
```

I have the following view model:

```
var viewModel = {
    CompnayNameFilter: ko.observable(),
    PhoneNumberFilter: ko.observable(),
    UsernameFilter: ko.observable(),
    DatabaseLocationFilter: ko.observable(),
    DoFilterOnFilteredData:ko.computed(function(){
          // code to update DoFilterOnFilteredData to false when any other observable changes
    })
}
```

My requirement is that whenever user enters a new value or changes the value in the `Company Name`, `Phone Number`, `User Name` and `Database Location` textboxes, I have to set the `DoFilterOnFilteredData` value to false. How can I achieve this? I think this is possible using a computed observable.

P.S: If possible, please provide a fiddle for this.

**EDIT:**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seadrag0n/dytre/

Comment: You don't provide a jsFiddle but expect we do?

Comment: It would be better for you to provide a fiddle with what you have so far and let people edit that, therefore people can recreate your issue without having to get your code working in the first place

Comment: @GôTô some problem with our office network, jsfiddle is not opening here

Comment: @seadrag0n There are other sites with the same functionality. Plus, how will you test the fiddle you ask for if you can't visit the site?

Comment: @GôTô added link to JSFiddle in my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using `subscribe` function:

```
self.CompnayNameFilter.subscribe(function (value) {
    self.DoFilterOnFilteredData(!!value);

});

self.PhoneNumberFilter.subscribe(function (value) {
    self.DoFilterOnFilteredData(!!value);
});

self.UsernameFilter.subscribe(function (value) {
    self.DoFilterOnFilteredData(!!value);
});

self.DatabaseLocationFilter.subscribe(function (value) {
    self.DoFilterOnFilteredData(!!value);      
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a modified working version of your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/dytre/4/

Comment: +1, But can be shortened to one external one-liner function: `self.DoFilterOnFilteredData(!!value);`.

Comment: @DianaNassar where should I write the subscribe code exactly? I added the subscribe code in a another function in my view model where I am calling my server side code to bind the data and subscribe functions doesn't seem to work..

Comment: No, not there. Add them anywhere in the viewmodel - after your observable declarations for example. They have to be in the viewmodel and not within another function.

Comment: @DianaNassar I am using the javascript closure syntax for my view model so I am confused where to add the observable subscriptions. Created fiddle, please modify it http://jsfiddle.net/seadrag0n/dytre/

Comment: @seadrag0n I have posted the complete working code. Also did some refactoring.

Comment: @DianaNassar thanks for editing my fiddle working fine now. Just one more question, is it ok to use both `beforeChange` and `change` events of `subscribe` method separately on an observable?

Comment: You're welcome! Of course you can, but I never needed to. Subscribe has been always sufficient for me but if there's some business / code need for that go ahead and do it.
You can read more about them here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html [ctrl+f "beforeChange"].

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete working example.

jsiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/dytre/3/

```
 var viewModel = {
    DoFilterOnFilteredData: ko.observable('true'),
    CompnayNameFilter: ko.observable(),
    PhoneNumberFilter: ko.observable(),
    UsernameFilter: ko.observable(),
    DatabaseLocationFilter: ko.observable(),
}

$(function () {
    var handler = function (value) {
        viewModel.DoFilterOnFilteredData( !! value);
    }
    viewModel.CompnayNameFilter.subscribe(handler);
    viewModel.PhoneNumberFilter.subscribe(handler);
    viewModel.UsernameFilter.subscribe(handler);
    viewModel.DatabaseLocationFilter.subscribe(handler);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```